# How to change position of postnote field in biblatex footcites?

Tags: biblatex

I am working with the `philosophy-verbose` style and modifying it quite successfully to accomplish my humanitarian needs. One thing that I can't achieve is to change the position of the postnote in the footnote reference. It is last in the reference now:

> CTAN. The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network, 2006, http://www.ctan.org (visited on 10/01/2006), p. 22.

I need it to be before URL, DOI and other links in all types of references (articles, online, books etc.):

> CTAN. The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network, 2006, p. 22, http://www.ctan.org (visited on 10/01/2006).

How can this be done?

I even commented out all lines of the `@article` driver in `philosophy-verbose.bbx`, but the postnote is still there in the output. So I can't insert the postnote where I want because it appears two times in the footnote.
Maybe I should modify `.cbx` file? Modifications of `.bbx` files are more or less understandable for me, but `.cbx` ones are mystery.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,backref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
Filler text.\footcite[22]{ctan}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you also want the page number before the ISBN? Do you want it before or after the `pagetotal` field?

Comment: I removed both fields from the output, but they can be useful in some situations, so let's say page number before ISBN but after pagetotal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\global\clearfield{postnote}` to get rid of the `postnote` for good once you have printed it.

First we define a bibmacro `bib:postnote` that prints the postnote and gets rid of it immediately afterwards, so it is not printed twice.

The second, longer part of the code below then just adds the new `bib:postnote` macro to all bibdrivers/bibmacros involved. I used `xpatch` for that and tried to cut some corners by using loops, but if you are already extensively modifiyng the bibliography drivers, you could manually add `\usebibmacro{bib:postnote}` in the right place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose, backref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

% only print the postnote if
% * we are in a citation (clear; this is needed because we will modify the bibdrivers)
% * we are at the last citation (that's where the postnote belongs)
% * the postnote field is a page range (if you don't like that, remove the
%   'and test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}').
\newbibmacro*{bib:postnote}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
        test {\ifcitation}
    and test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}}
    and test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}%
     \global\clearfield{postnote}}
    {}}


% patch the bib drivers
% I'll use some helper macros, so will make @ a letter
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\marasblx@errpatch@bibdriver}[1]{%
  \PackageError{mod-biblatex-philosophy}
    {Failed to patch bibdriver for '@#1'}
    {}}
\newcommand*{\marasblx@errpatch@bibmacro}[1]{%
  \PackageError{mod-biblatex-philosophy}
    {Failed to patch bibmacro '#1'}
    {}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{article}
  {\usebibmacro{note+pages}}
  {\usebibmacro{note+pages}%
   \usebibmacro{bib:postnote}}
  {}{\errpatchbibdriver{article}}

\newcommand*{\marasblx@patch@bibdrivers@chapandpages}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
    {\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
     \usebibmacro{bib:postnote}}
    {}{\marasblx@errpatch@bibdriver{#1}}}
\forcsvlist{\marasblx@patch@bibdrivers@chapandpages}{%
  book,booklet,collection,manual,proceedings,report,thesis,jurisdiction}

\newcommand*{\marasblx@patch@bibmacro@chapandpages}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibmacro{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
    {\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
     \usebibmacro{bib:postnote}}
    {}{\marasblx@errpatch@bibmacro{#1}}}
\forcsvlist{\marasblx@patch@bibmacro@chapandpages}{%
  inbook:full,incollection:full,inproceedings:full}

\xpatchbibdriver{misc}
  {\usebibmacro{organization+location+date}}
  {\usebibmacro{organization+location+date}%
   \usebibmacro{bib:postnote}}
  {}{\marasblx@errpatch@bibdriver{misc}}

\newcommand*{\marasblx@patch@bibdrivers@date}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{date}}
    {\usebibmacro{date}%
     \usebibmacro{bib:postnote}}
    {}{\marasblx@errpatch@bibdriver{#1}}}
\forcsvlist{\marasblx@patch@bibdrivers@date}{%
  online,patent}

\xpatchbibdriver{periodical}
  {\printfield{note}}
  {\printfield{note}%
   \usebibmacro{bib:postnote}}
  {}{\marasblx@errpatch@bibdriver{periodical}}

\xpatchbibdriver{unpublished}
  {\usebibmacro{location+date}}
  {\usebibmacro{location+date}%
   \usebibmacro{bib:postnote}}
  {}{\marasblx@errpatch@bibdriver{unpublished}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
Filler text.\footcite[22]{ctan}
Filler text.\footcite[380]{sigfridsson}
Filler text.\footcite[23]{ctan}
Filler text.\footcite[381]{sigfridsson}
Filler text.\footcite{pines}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: CTAN. The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network, 2006, p. 22, http://www.ctan.org (visited on 10/01/2006).]

Comment: Wow, create such difficult code is not for my skills and knowledge. You are awesome, @moewe! Thank you very much! Your bibmacro is working perfectly. I inserted it in the bibliography drivers, because your patch code threw errors about not being able to patch the drivers – I modified style files too much, I think.